# Shooting method of an arrow in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create shooting method of spinning arrow in SpriteKit, the idea of how I want it is when I touch the screen arrow object will be created and spinning till the touch end will pushed base on its rotation i tried these methods

```
func radiansToVector(radians: CGFloat) -> CGVector {
    return CGVector(dx: cos(radians), dy: sin(radians))
}

func shoot ()->()
    {
        let rotationVector : CGVector = radiansToVector(sprite.zRotation)
        sprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(rotationVector.dx * shootSpeed , rotationVector.dy * shootSpeed)
    }
```

But the way of its shooting its not like what I want it goes based on the side of the arrow (for example: if the arrow through its rotation was straight to up and the touch ended its goes horizontally instead of vertically).

Comment: I suggest that you rotate your arrow with an image editing app so that it points to the right when `zRotation` = 0. If not, you will need to offset your `zRotation` calculation appropriately.

Comment: seems helpful can you please describe more how i can do what you said ?

Comment: How did you create the arrow image? Use that app to rotate the arrow so that it points to the right.

Comment: Use that image instead of the original one. Set the velocity using the code that you posted.

Comment: actually it worked thank u buddy (Y)